# Ruby On Rails Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite3-ruby

Whenever I run the command `rvmsudo rake db:migrate` (I need to use `rvmsudo` because I'm using rvm), the sqlite3 files generated are owned by root.

`ls -l db/*.sqlite3`

Because of this, I keep on getting a SQLite3 Read Only Error whenever I try to do anything to the database, and I have to manually enter the command:

`sudo chown -R myusername db/*.sqlite3`

`rvmsudo rake db:migrate` never did this before, and I am wondering why it is happening now.

Comment: If I don't I get permission denied

Comment: I figured out what was wrong.

I was using `rvmsudo db:migrate` from the start, which set the sqlite3 file's users to root. I am using `rake db:migrate` now (without the rvmsudo), and it generates the sqlite3 files as my user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you install RVM as root, and if so, is there a reason it wasn't installed as your normal (less-privileged) user?  I use RVM daily, on a number of machines, and haven't had to install RVM as root.